# max-width image doesn't expand the parent container

Tags: html, image, css

I have image thumbnails floated to the left. The code is as follows:

```
  <div id="imgContainer">
    <div>
     <a href="#" class="item"><img src="image.png" /></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#imgContainer div {
   width: 23%;
   float: left;
   padding: 1%;
   position: relative;
}

#imgContainer img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 290px;
}
```

And the problem is:
It stretches the images to 290px only by width. It doesn't seem to affect the height. which results in really stretched thumbnails. I need them to be 290px max width and the height should scale accordingly.

Comment: This works fine for me ... http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/

Comment: Thanks, David :) Now I have another poroblem. What height should I set the parent container so it goes under the rest of the thumbnails? See http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/11/

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/12/ I removed the position: absolute stuff as I wasn't sure why you wanted it in there.

Comment: Dave, thanks. But, unfortunately I need the absolute positioning because every set of thumbnails had 2 images on top of one another :/ Is there another way to conquer this?

Comment: Can you make an example of what you're doing on jsfiddle to see if I can work something out?

Comment: Yes, thanks for taking the time :) Here's a simplified thing of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/31/

Comment: This should do it, http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/37/

Comment: Maan you are awesome :) I have some other images overlapping on hover but I just gave them like img:nth-child(3) and img:nth-child(4) also absolute positioning. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. You may want to use nth-child(n+2) (skips the first image, but applies it to the rest): http://jsfiddle.net/BuZPL/38/ .. saves you writing nth-child(3) ... nth-child(4) etc ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Any dimension that isn't specified should scale automatically, but your images may be inheriting styles that dictates other wise. To revert to automatic scaling height, you should specify the following property for `#imgContainer img`:

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you mark my post as the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
#imgContainer img { height: 100% }
```

or

```
#imgContainer img { height: auto }
```

should be enough.